# How to prevent video request every time a slide showing a video?

Tags: javascript, browser, slick.js

I am using [Slick.js](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and create a slideshow containing videos. Every time a slide showing a video the browser sent request to the server and get 304. The video still playing well but when the connection to the internet disconnected the video stopped playing. I see in network console the browser sent request to server and then failed. The video not playing.

How to prevent browser request to server and get content from cache instead when internet goes offline? I want the video slide to play forever even when the internet disconnected.

Below is the screenshot of network tab in developer console.

[image]

Here is the video tag.

```
<video preload="auto" muted>
       <source src="https://www.media.co/ilm_dart.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

And here is the slick script.

```
var slideshow = $(".slider");
    slideshow.slick({
        initialSlide: 0,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 10000,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        pauseOnFocus: false,
        arrows: false,
    });
```

Comment: progressive web app. you can use workbox library to ease out strategies for it to work offline

Comment: thanks. btw, is that the only way? @joyBlanks